# Can we make nfc card readable but only to specific devices?

Tags: android, nfc

I am working on nfc card and i am totally new on it. I am working on android device and till now i am able to read and write in nfc tag. but is it possible to make nfc tag readable to only my specific devices? Please help.

Comment: I think you should at least try it once and then ask why/how you got stocked

Comment: NFC Card holds data which can be scanned by any NFC Reader. If you want the data to be protected, I suggest you encrypt the data and save in the NFC Card. With this, even if any other device, scans the card, they will see encrypted data, rather than the original data. And in your device, you can program your NFC Reader App to decrypt the scanned data. This could be a possible solution to your question. However, it may not be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: You can't make it readable only for your devices.

Answer (score 1):

That depends, as you don't specify the Make and Model of the Cards you are using and how you want the cards to be read (either with an App or by the OS) then it is difficult to say.

But a number of card formats allow you to password protect data on the card, a read attempt to a password protected area will return an error/empty/blank data.

Some card types also offer the ability to limit the number of password attempts

As long as you keep the password secure in your App then and limit the Apps ability to use the password to those devices you want to be able to read the cards then you can limit readable of a card to specific devices.

Practically this is not much different what somebody else suggested of just encrypting the data on the card and having it still readable to all.

Also note that without the password limiting some older cards password protection is in the realms of crackable.